# Jquery, php, http 500 error on production site

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery issue, I think it's a jquery issue, but I'm calling a php page with a ajax call. Obviously this is easy, but when I go live with it I keep getting a 500 error. I have tried everything I can think of.  But I'm not getting anywhere.  I'm sure it's because I'm not a jquery guru, so if you are I could use your brain.

keep in mind this works locally but not in production:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($('#signupForm').valid())
  {
    var data = $('#signupForm').serializeObject();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://pathtooweb.com/funcs/signup.php',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        toastr.success(data, "Thank you!");
        $("#signupForm").trigger( "reset" );
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the actual issue I am getting on console:

```
POST http://pathtooweb.com/funcs/signup.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:7845
x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send jquery.js:7845
x.extend.ajax jquery.js:7301
(anonymous function) pathtooweb.com/:84
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:4676
y.handle
```

UPDATE:

This was not a cross domain issue, it was a server error in a way.. come to find out when I was pushing my code up to github then down to my server one of the libraries I was using was not uploading to github, so in turn wasn't being pulled down to the server. Can't really say why there was no .gitignore file. so anyway, thanks for the "suggestions". :)

Comment: 500 is an internal server error, so it's not jQuery !

Comment: 500 is a _server_ error, but jQuery runs on the _client_. Look at your server logs. I'd guess there's some difference between the production server configuration and your local server config.

Comment: well I thought that was the case, but I have checked all my configs. This did not happen until I uploaded the recent code. It worked at one point.  What I don't get with that is why it still does local and not on the server.

Comment: Let's see your PHP code

Comment: it helps to check the actual server logs (apache, nginx, etc), when possible. This is tough on shared hosting sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Dude I guess you are trying a cross domain POST..!! Which is not allowed via ajax.. and is a strict NO NO as per web standards.!!

Possibly locally you are using a different URL in the ajax request.. which is also hosted locally.. Is it the case??

If you want a cross domain POST.. directly post the form to that URL by having the form action URL as the crossdomain URL.

The second option will be to use jsonP as the datatype in the ajax request.. this is a hack but works.